# How to avoid case sensitivity in Python

Tags: python, case-sensitive

I have this code and want to compare two lists.

```
list2= [('Tom','100'),('Alex','200')]
list3= [('tom','100'),('alex','200')]

non_match = []
for line in list2:
    if line not in list3:
       non_match.append(line)

print(non_match)
```

The results will be:

```
[('Tom', '100'), ('Alex', '200')]
```

because of case sensitivity! is there any way to avoid the case sensitivity in this case? I don't want to change the lists to upper or lower case.

Or any other method which can match these lists?

Comment: You will have to convert the strings either in upper or lower case while doing the comparison. What do you mean by _"I don't want to change the lists to upper or lower case."_

Comment: You don't want to convert anything to lower or upper case? Because that will be a problem. Or you just want the output to be in the same case as the input is in?

Comment: if you don't convert strings to uppercase or lowercase before you compare, you may end up trying compare 2^n strings before you can say it is not in the other list

Comment: @ozata for that approach, he'll still have to search all possible cases of the input string, which means, he'll still need to convert to some other cases.

Comment: because the output should be in the same case as the input is and these lists are stored in a DB. cost resources to change

Comment: @DrikDrik what is your desired output here - an empty result list? If you had `list2 = [('bob', 10)]` and `list3 = [('jim', 20)]` what would the output be then?

Comment: Also - if you're getting this from a DB in whatever way - would it be more practical to change the query you're using to have the DB do this for you to start with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me! Both lists will be converted to lower case.

```
list2= [('Tom','100'),('Alex','200'),('Tom', '13285')]
list3= [('tom','100'),('ALex','200'),('Tom', '13285')]


 def make_canonical(line):
     name, number = line
     return (name.lower(), number)

 list22 = []
 for line2 in list2:
    search = make_canonical(line2)
    list22.append(search)


 list33 =[]
 for line3 in list3:
     search1 = make_canonical(line3)
     list33.append(search1)


 non_match = []
 for line in list22:
     if line not in list33:
        non_match.append(line)


 print(non_match)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using lower to convert the tuple to lower case for comparison

```
list2= [('Tom','100'),('Alex','200')]
list3= [('tom','100'),('alex','200')]

non_match = []
for line in list2:
    name, val = line
    if (name.lower(), val) not in list3:
        non_match.append(line)

print(non_match)
```

Comment: You need to copy list3 to lowercase as well for this to work

Comment: how can i do that? in de samen line?

Comment: you can avoid the creation of an intermediate list for each tuple.

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid transforming your data to some case-insensitive format, *at some point*.
What you can do is to avoid recreating the full lists:

```
def make_canonical(line):
    name, number = line
    return (name.lower(), number)

non_match = []
for line2 in list2:
    search = make_canonical(line2)
    for line3 in list3:
        canonical = make_canonical(line3)
        if search == canonical:
            break
    else:
        # Did not hit the break
        non_match.append(line3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate tuples also inside loop

```
for line2 in list2:   
    for line3 in list3:
        if len(line3) == len(line2):
        lenth = len(line3)
            successCount = 0
        match = False
        for i in range(lenth):
            result = line2[i].lower() == line3[i].lower()
        if result == True:
            successCount = successCount +1;
            result = False
            if successCount == lenth:
            non_match.append(line2)




print(non_match)
```

enjoy.....

Answer (score 0):

You can make the comparison even more generic mixing `int`s and whitespaces in the game by creating two dicts from your tuple-lists and compare the lists:

```
def unify(v):
    return str(v).lower().strip()


list2= [('Tom    ','100'),('    AleX',200)]
list3= [('toM',100),('aLex  ','200')]

d2 = {unify(k):unify(v) for k,v in list2}  # create a dict
d3 = {unify(k):unify(v) for k,v in list3}  # create another dict

print(d2 == d3)  # dicts compare (key,value) wise
```

The applied methods will make strings from integers, strip whitespaces and then compare the dicts.

Output:

```
True
```